# Poisoning A Package/Function in GO

Tags: go

TLDR: Is there a way in golang (even if it is a bit non-standard), to "poison" a function or import of a certain package altogether.

The longer version: I am writing a thrift service, which all public facing functions return results, or an error of a certain type, declared in the thrift file. The code generator generates code for the interface like this:

```
publicFacingFunc(...) (returnType, error)
```

This would be great, until someone I am working with decides to check for another condition, and when that condition is not met does something like this:

```
if conditionIsNotMet {
    return nil, errors.New(...)
}
```

The code compiles, but when the error arises, the received message is undocumented random string. So in these files, I want to prevent usage of "errors" and "fmt" packages.

And yes, I tried, and still have I a blaring warning at the top of the file, but nobody seems to read.

BTW, the public errors all have a respective "constructor", which is external to these files, and only those should be used, in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only concerned with a packages use within a file, you could import it under a silly name, like 'NEVER'... and people could use it, but they'd get the idea I think.

```
 import (
      NEVER "fmt"
 )
```

OR, if you want to be less silly, you could use the `_` underscore, https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_import

```
import (
    _ "fmt"
)
```

which will load the import, but only it's side effects (that is, not for explicit use.

---

To stop the input of all errors not of a certain type, you could use `reflect` in order to stop the undesirable types with type assertion, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

```
v, ok = x.(T)
```

So if an `err` comes up in the public facing function, that you don't want passed through, check what kind of error it is,

```
 specialError, ok := err.(mypackage.ErrorType)
    if !ok {
        // don't send this error on
    }
```

Comment: While it is sufficient for my case, it is worth noting that go allows multiple imports of the same package, thereby making circumventing this scheme, somewhat easy. Nothing other than a review to prevent someone from re-declaring `_ "errors"` on another line as `"errors"`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to enforce it, you could do a build step that checks the output of [`go list`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages) for all of your packages, and make sure `fmt` and `errors` are not in the list of direct imports. With such common packages though, it could be difficult to avoid altogether. You could do more detailed parsing to detect `fmt.Errorf` or whatever, but could be tricky.

A more invasive solution would be modifying package source for those packages and forcing devs to use your custom go distribution. Probably too hard to pull off for the `fmt` and `errors` packages that are used literally everywhere in the std lib, but it may work for other packages. I would never recommend it though. Definitely add it as a build-time validation that runs on checkins and PRs and things.